# How to block device trying to connect to your wifi

Tags: wifi, block, hostapd

In my log-file I see that hostapd shows that a device is continuously trying to connect and disconnect which slows down the network & pollutes the log-file and.

Anyone knows how to block a device from trying to access your wifi? This will result in a less polluted log-file + faster network, since this continuous requests slow down the wifi.

Log-file looks like this:

```
Sun Jan 17 15:05:39 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Sun Jan 17 15:05:39 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 2)
Sun Jan 17 15:05:48 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request
Sun Jan 17 15:05:59 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Sun Jan 17 15:05:59 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 2)
Sun Jan 17 15:06:08 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request
Sun Jan 17 15:06:20 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Sun Jan 17 15:06:20 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 2)
Sun Jan 17 15:06:29 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request
Sun Jan 17 15:06:41 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Sun Jan 17 15:06:41 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 2)
Sun Jan 17 15:06:50 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request
Sun Jan 17 15:07:01 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Sun Jan 17 15:07:01 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 2)
Sun Jan 17 15:07:10 2016 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA 00:04:20:xx:yy:zz IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request
```

ps. I have blocked the mac-address on the router (network, but that doesn't seem to solve the issue (probably because that block will be done after the initial handshake?)).

Comment: If you're having performance issues due to a single device trying to connect every 10-20 seconds, you likely have larger problems to solve. Wifi is a broadcast medium - you cannot prevent devices from trying to join your network.

Comment: Hi EEAA, thanks for your response. 98% the network works very well, however in 2% of the times the router is getting slow & i have the idea this is because of the above. Since when checking with top-command, I dont see anything taking a lot of processing power. That said, its annoying that this unknown device pollutes the log-files. And it should be possible to block a device right?

Comment: Try hiding your SSID and changing it to a new name. Your wifi network will not appear to the average outsider then.

Comment: Thanks user987654321, your perfect simple answer is really of great help, it worked! Thanks a lot for sharing your thoughts :-)